# How to put Java object to ObjectNode in Jackson?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am composing `ObjectNode` programmtically and I am filling it's fields with `put(String propertyName...)` methods. Now I want to add a subobject, which I already have in the form of Java object. How to do this?

I don't have `put(String propertyName, Object value)` method, so what to do?

I am able to create

```
JsonNode node = mapper.valueToTree(myObject);
```

but again I don't have `put(String propertyName, JsonNode node)` method.

How to accomplish?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `set(String, JsonNode)` instead of `put`. Example below:

```
Car car = new Car();
car.setName("My car");
car.setYear("2022");

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

ObjectNode baseNode = mapper.createObjectNode();
ObjectNode carNode = mapper.valueToTree(car);

baseNode.put("hello", "world");
baseNode.set("car", carNode);

System.out.println(baseNode.toPrettyString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Can use [`set(String propertyName, JsonNode node)`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/node/ObjectNode.html#set(java.lang.String,%20com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode)) method.

Comment: oh I see you already answered this while I was formatting :)